# Two Column CSS - Right Column Fixed Width, Left Column ariable

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to work out how to get a "two column" type website. Well it's really the main body with a right column floated right.

Normally I'd float before the body and set a margin-right on the body and achieve the desired thing.

However with Google and SEO, I need to be more creative as the right column should be after the main content which should have a higher prioritisation than the column for textual indexing.

Gah.

So I come up with this.

Critique please:

```
<div id="bodycontainer" style="border:1px solid #0f0; width:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; overflow:hidden;">
<div id="bodyoffset" style="border:1px solid #f00; width:100%; margin-left:-210px; overflow:hidden; float:left;">
    <div id"bodyrestrict" style="border:1px solid #ff0; margin-left:210px;">
    Main Column<br/>
    Some text goes here.<br/><br/>
    I want this column to fill up the remainder space that is filled by the...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="newscolumn" style="border:1px solid #00f; width:200px; float:left;">
    ...Right Column
</div>
<p style="clear:both;"></p>
```

This makes sense to me, the bodycontainer controls overall width, bodyoffset has a negative left margin so we can float the newscolumn onto the right, but bodyrestrict then brings the body back inline by offsetting the negative margin with a positive margin.

Some magic voodoo jiggery pokery but it seems to work.

Is there a better way?

Obviously I don't know what the body element should actually be (and I don't want to go down the JavaScript route if I can help it). So I can't set a width of say 100%-200px or whatever (be good if I could). And I don't want it a fixed width, I want it to expand to fill the screen.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Does this mean the left column sings opera?

Comment: I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/P7vsu/1/ .  Also, I copied what you wrote into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KhYLh/ .  It does seem like a lot to go through for what you want though, but if you can manage the math then go for it.

Comment: Your method is perfectly fine; is there something that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Thanks ProfileTwist - no just wondered if that was an OK way of programming or whether there was something obvious Im missing to do it right. asafreedman, thanks for that one too... but I do like exact pixel widths for columns. Percentages are so much easier because if one is 10% the other is 90%. But if one is 100px, then what do you make the other to fill up the screen!

Answer (score 0):

floatting doesn't need funny negative margins ? or i didnot understand what you meant.

Here's example with

1. floatting
2. display (inline-block was already proposed)
3. display +reverse order (works with inline-block if you wish)

: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xnlGa

You have display:flex as well , but not yet good enough implemented actually in my own opinion :)